# SQL Server make sure a value exists in the table specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have a Table that has a value column and a TableName columns. I'm trying to make a CHECK constraint that makes sure that the value in the value column exists in the table that is specified in the TableName.

We don't want to have different tables for each TableName since they all need to tie back to one table and there would be thousands of different possible values for TableName.

Any ideas how to do this?

Example data:

```
INSERT INTO [Propagation].[AgencyEntityBroadcast](
EntityID, AgencyID, ReferenceTableName, ReferenceTableSchemaName)
VALUES('DF298C2D-D960-4F32-A071-685CCAE9B573', '0BDFFBD6-5502-4392-B67D-86B477954186', 'AgencyVehicle', 'Resource')
```

So I want to make sure that the Value 'DF298C2D-D960-4F32-A071-685CCAE9B573' exists in the primary key column of the [Resource].[AgencyVehicle] table.

Comment: Can you give some example data?

Comment: Could you expand with example data and an expected result if value does and does not exist please?

Comment: What should happen when somebody issues a delete of a row from table A that contains value V, and that value is somehow required? Exception ? Failed transaction ?

Comment: In our system we only do soft deletes so this shouldn't be an issue. But on the off chance that does happen it would result in an orphan record.

Comment: TSQL Scalar UDFs can't execute dynamic SQL so unless you fancy having some giant conditional logic for the thousands of table names you won't be able to use those.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I suppose we could just make all interactions with this table go through SPROCs and have them do any dynamic sql checks.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a check constraint here you need a foreign key constraint here something like this ....

```
ALTER TABLE [Propagation].[AgencyEntityBroadcast]
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_EntityID  FOREIGN KEY (EntityID)
REFERENCES [Resource].[AgencyVehicle](PK_Column_Name)
```

Comment: Except the TableName could be 'AgencyFacility' or 'AgencyMedication'..etc so it would have to be a key that does a refferences 'AgencyVehicle' OR 'AgencyFacility' ..etc